# Getting student name with highest total mark in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have table named 'marks' which stores marks of students.

```
     id name      social math   science
     2  Max Ruin    85   85      56 
     3  Arnold      75   40      170
     4  Krish       60   70      50
     5  John        60   90      80
```

I want to get the name of student who has highest total mark.

I tried query like this

```
 SELECT name, (social + math +science) AS total_mark FROM marks where total_mark = max(total_mark );
```

But this is not working. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: What if there are ties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

get the `max()` total first then use a `subquery`

```
    select * from marks where (social+math+science) =    
      (select max(social+math+science) from marks);
```

Comment: Hi METAL, this is not working. when i try this i am getting the first student record as result always.

Comment: Please note that this query may return more than one result if there are more than one student with the max grade.

Comment: @Chrᴉz, this is what the OP wants. your answer was my first answer.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ Thanks to you I noticed a error on my answer :). I interpreted _get the name of student who has_ as the single best one.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
 SELECT *,(SUM(social)+SUM(math)+SUM(science)) AS total_mark FROM `marks` GROUP BY id ORDER BY total_mark DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rank() function to get the rank of the persons.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT name, (social + math + science) as total_mark, Rank() OVER (ORDER BY  (social + math + science) DESC) AS rnk
FROM marks)t
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select social + math + science as total, marks.*
from marks
order by social + math + science desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Unfortuantely, sqlfiddle didnt work with `fetch first 1 rows only`. My previous answer produced a wrong result.

Comment: `fetch first` is supported starting in Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one student, then you can do this without a subquery:

```
select max(name) keep (dense_rank first order by (social + math + science) desc) as top_name
from marks;
```